# Windows 8.1 64-bit Text Editor for Command Prompt?

Tags: windows-8.1, 64-bit, text-editors

I have used text editors such as -- pico, vi, Emacs, nano, et cetera. I noticed that the windows 8 64-bit Command prompt no longer uses "edit" as far as I can tell.

Is there a recommended editor windows 8.1 64-bit users have, or does everyone just write their trivial programs outside of the command prompt?

In the instance that someone has a suggestion for me to use, I would greatly appreciate a link to an installation guide or further information aside from just a name.

Thanks for the time anyone spends to assist me.

Comment: Well, `edit.com` is a 16-bit application, and [64-bit versions of Windows don't support them](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896458/en-us) - unlike 32-bit versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are used to vi, you could try gVim:

http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc

You could also try WinVi:

http://www.winvi.de/en/

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time people use wordpad or notepad (which can be executed from the prompt) but you could use third party tools.